# how to compare the entire user input in android taken through edit text with a hard coded string

Tags: android

this is what I tried doing:

```
 EditText text_ans1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ans_one);
 String ans1 = text_ans1.getText().toString();
 if(ans1=="abc")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings with `==` in Java.

This is the correct way:

```
if( ans1.equals("abc") )
```

Answer (score 2):

The **==** operator is comparing references, that's not what you want.
Like @aletede91 said you have to use the [equals](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method to compare values